# Uninitialized member not caught by compiler. Is it a bug?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++17

As a bad c++ programmer, I encountered this segfault today: an uninitialized shared_ptr
gave a NULL, and my program crashed. With normal class members I get warnings or errors if the member is uninitialized. But not in this case. I've produced a repro below.

In debug mode this segfaults. I get no compiler errors or warnings on uninitialized variables, which I expected.

Is this a bug? Or am I misunderstanding.
Should the compiler not warn or error out on this code?

I would not want this to compile at all!

I think that the compiler should error out and say that you need to initialize the private `wooo` in the class constructor...

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Wooo{
public:
    int maybe;
    int istrue(){
        return maybe + 1;}
private:
    Wooo(); // just to be explicit about deleted default constructor
};

class Weee{
public:
    Weee(){}; // just empty constructor. reading wooo anywhere will give a NULL
    
    Wooo seg_me(){
        return *wooo.get();
    };
private:
    const std::shared_ptr<Wooo> wooo;
};

int main()
{   
    auto w = Weee();
    cout<<"Hello World\n";
    cout<< w.seg_me().istrue() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, it *is* initialized... to `nullptr`. I'm afraid your compiler isn't smart enough to warn you about you dereferencing that null pointer, but maybe another static analyzer would.

Comment: Identifying instances of *Undefined Behavior* or other questionable code falls under *Quality of Implementation*, because doing so can range all the way from trivial to impossible even if you could solve the halting problem. Compilers generally just assume it doesn't happen, and aggressively prune paths where it will to make up for imperfect information and achieve efficient code. Leaving traps for identification at runtime generally impairs efficiency, and is thus relegated to debug mode and low optimization.

Comment: can confirm, this behavior is caught by the undefined behavior sanitizer. building with -fsanitize=undefined lights it up like a Christmas tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> an uninitialized shared_ptr ...

> I think that the compiler should error out and say that you need to initialize the private wooo

It's *not* uninitialized. It's just default-initialized. By its default constructor. To `nullptr`.

A not-explicitly-initialized `shared_ptr` is equivalent to a raw pointer like

```
Wooo *wooo = nullptr;
```

> Is this a bug?

Yes, it's a bug in your code: you allowed the pointer to be default-initialized, and then dereferenced it before actually pointing it somewhere.

---

You have two possible cases:

1. It is *never* permissible for `Weee::wooo` to contain a `nullptr`

   In this case the bug is that you wrote a constructor that failed to establish your class invariants.

   You should instead have

   ```
   Weee() : wooo{make_shared ...} {}
   ```

   and/or

   ```
   explicit Weee(shared_ptr<Wooo>&& p) : wooo{std::move(p)} {}
   ```

   or whatever.

   The point is that **if** having a non-nullptr member is a class invariant, then **any** constructor or method that may leave this unsatisfied is wrong.
2. It is sometimes permissible for `Weee::wooo` to contain a `nullptr`, either because you have 2-phase initialization (boo) or because it's effectively optional or conditional.

   In this case the bug is that you didn't check whether the pointer was (quite legally) a `nullptr` before de-referencing it.

Comment: Ok. This mostly answers what I was wondering about. What I expected was the compiler to see my bug (in forgetting to write the proper constructor) How would one catch that case with types?

Comment: You can write a smart pointer that's constrained to be non-null, if that's the desired behaviour, like `not_null` in the [GSL](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md). But you still need to decide what the intended semantics are in the first place, and you haven't addressed that yet.